# ClassCastException: android.widget.ListView cannot be cast to android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to make the items in my list view clickable but I keep running into this error on android studio saying that it cannot resolve symbol `OnItemClickListener()` on the line `new OnItemClickListener` and asks if I am talking about `ArrayView.onItemClickListener`.

The same happens if I try to extend `OnItemClickListener` and even if I cast `new (ListView) OnItemClickListener`. When I hover over it it says `setOnItemClickListener (android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) in adapter view cannot be applied`.

This is what I have so far and I tried it another way also which is the second half but, this time, the error was also the `this` in parenthesis and I keep getting the other attempt error of `OnItemClickListener (andorid……`

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class Create extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstancesState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstancesState);
    setContentView(R.layout.create);

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(                                  
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    ArrayAdapter<String> list = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.contacts_list_item);   



    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {                    

        String name = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        list.add(name);                                                     

    }



       ListView lstView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        lstView.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int pos, long ld) {

                }

        });
setListAdapter(list);

    }
```

This is the second way I tried it but still highlights red under `this`

```
  lstView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

       TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_text_list);
                    String clickText = tv.getText().toString();
                    Log.d("My Activity", clickText);

    } 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong method to assign the listener

Change

```
 lstView.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int pos, long ld) {

            }

    });
```

to

```
  lstview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

     }
  });
```

Comment: That got rid of most of the erros but there is still one on new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(). "Class anonymous class derived from OnItemClickListener must be declared abstract or implement abstract method onItemClick(AdapterView<?>......

Comment: lstView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {                              @Override
                    public void onItemClickListener (AdapterView < ? > a, View v,int pos, long ld){

                }

                });

Comment: It works now thanks, I have one final question which is if I add this code which was edited on the second part of my original question in the inside of onItemClick why doesnt it show on logcat

Comment: Can you see items in list view?? and do you see other logs in logcat??

Comment: There are items in the list view I tried looking at all of them but nothing was printed no matter how many times I pressed

Comment: Sorry what do you mean ? I looked under verbose, debug, error, assert, info and warn if thats what you are talking but nothing that has the string "My Activity"

Comment: Remove all codes from that method and put this to see if something shows up on the screen.  `Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Create.this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();`

Comment: Nothing happens when I made the changes. I am running it on an AVD and the xml uses relative layout with the listview inside it if its worth mentioning

Comment: Please post you full code in a new question. Original problem is solved. I ll look into that.

Comment: Also, please accept it as answer. It solved problem mentioned in the question, right?

Comment: please try this `lstView.setItemsCanFocus(false);` after `ListView lstView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);`